# substitution" gz topic -1" for gazebo version 2.2.3

Tags: gazebo-2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i'm using gazebo 2 and i want to know what topics are running on my system
what can i do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9148/substitution%22-gz-topic--1%22-for-gazebo-version-2.2.3/) by [soshiant1992](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1308/soshiant1992/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could try [gztopic list](https://vimeo.com/61543492)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soshiant1992](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1308/soshiant1992/) on 2015-08-17**:
perfect thanx